# What is the best way to convert XMLGregorianCalendar to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm String?

Tags: java, xml

What is the best way to convert XMLGregorianCalendar objects to 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm' String?

Answer (score 45):

First use [`XMLGregorianCalendar#toGregorianCalendar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28%29) to get a [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance out of it.

```
Calendar calendar = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar();
```

From that step on, it's all obvious with a little help of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the usual way.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
formatter.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
String dateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

I only wonder if you don't actually want to use `HH` instead of `hh` as you aren't formatting the am/pm marker anywhere.

Comment: When I do this conversion the result is '02/26/2010 06:39:24 PM'. But xmlGregorianCalendar.toString() returns '2010-02-26T10:39:24-06:00'. So why result is converted in different TimeZone?

Comment: Please keep in mind that "hh:mm" is 1-12 hour format. For 0-23 format use "HH:mm"!

Comment: @FCR: I just took over OP's own pattern. See also question itself and last paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use 
[`toGregorianCalendar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28java.util.TimeZone,%20java.util.Locale,%20javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar%29) method for this.

E.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
String date = sdf.format(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
```

In case, you need to convert that calendar to different TimeZone and Locale, use [`toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone timezone, Locale aLocale, XMLGregorianCalendar defaults)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28java.util.TimeZone,%20java.util.Locale,%20javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar%29)

Comment: I believe that SimpleDateFormatter should be SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

This is an example you are looking for:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar date = ...; // initialization is out of scope for this example
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
GregorianCalendar gc = date.toGregorianCalendar();
String formatted_string = sdf.format(gc.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

This example [convert XMLGregorianCalendar to date](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-xml/convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-date.html)

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
Date date = xmlCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

This example [convert date to string](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-common/convert-date-to-string-in-java.html)

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
String dateStr = df.format(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this static utility. You just mentioned a pattern like "ddMMyy" or "HHmm" or what ever you want.. this will work wonderfully.

```
public static String getDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar gDate, String pattern){

    return Optional.ofNullable(gDate)
            .map(gdate -> {
                Calendar calendar = gDate.toGregorianCalendar();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                formatter.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
                return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
            })
            .orElse(null);
}
```