# From xmlGregorianCalender to date with specific format

Tags: java, date

Hi I have this method

```
public static Date toDate(XMLGregorianCalendar calendar) 
  if (calendar == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return calendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
}
```

The date I get from this method is with this format     `Fri May 30 12:00:00 EEST 2014` but I wan the format to be like     `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` any idea how ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060161/specify-the-date-format-in-xmlgregoriancalendar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031903/xmlgregoriancalendar-formatting-in-mm-dd-yyyy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392811/date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar-with-specific-format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688526/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-xmlgregoriancalendar-to-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-string are all very similar and would answer your question. Google really should be your first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date object as per your need.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date()));
```

output:

```
11-06-2014 21:13:49
```

You are getting default `toString()` implementation of `Date` object.

Find the source code here [Date#toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29) that uses `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` pattern.

Comment: Thankkkkkkkkks alot :D